# Need help solving EventHandler issue

Tags: java, input, events, keyboard

I have an issue with my EventHandler for Key events in my game.

The specifics are in this forum thread: http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/problems-with-key-event-handling/37998/view.html

Basically, the issue is that a KeyReleasedEvent is fired in a very inconvenient way. I recently switched from polling to interrupting to take key input, so I'm hoping somebody has had this problem before and knows an elegant way to solve it.

I can provide more code and details if needed. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In short, you want to track whether each key is pressed separately. I can't speak to the engine you're using, but normal java events for a key being released tell you which key with `getKeyChar()` or `getKeyCode()`, even for key released events.

You can make an `int` variable for the handler object and set it equal to the key code in the `keyPressed` handler. Then, in your `keyReleased` handler, only stop the movement if the current key code equals the value of the `int` that holds the last keycode pressed.

Comment: Based on some advice I got on reddit i'm going to go back to polling for this. Their reasoning was that polling is superior for operations that rely on frame-by-frame changes whereas interrupting is better for stuff like press 'i' to bring up an inventory menu.